# Get how many percentage where statement match mysql

Tags: mysql, where-clause, percentage

Is there any possibility to get the percentage of how much a where statement match right in the SQL question?

Something like the PHP function similiar_text (http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php)

My thoughts is to, right in the SQL question, check if the where statement match more than 95% then it should proceed.

Is this possible? If yes how do I do?

**EDIT:**

Table: Car

```
id type description
1 Toyota Nice car that runs very fast and have a big engine.
```

Then I have the string containing the following
$description = 'Very very Nice car that runs very fast and have a very big engine."

I want to check the table "Car" if there is any description thats is 95% like any existing with my $description string. If there isn't it should be added to the table. If there is a 95% match or more it should not be added to the table

**EDIT2:**
My code now looks like this:

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM table
                            WHERE MATCH (title)
                            AGAINST ("The test text here " IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)');

$i = 1;

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    echo $i . '. ';
    echo $row->title;
    echo "<br>";

    $i++;
}
```

Above code gives me the "most matching" result first and the second after and so on. Now I get this printed out. I see a solution where I use PHP function similar_text on the first match which is printed out and get the percentage of the match. After that I can decide if it match 95% or more I want add the post to the DB . But is there a way for me to not do this in my PHP code and instead right in the SQL question?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected results to clarify what you are asking for?

Comment: Edited my post, if you don't understand please tell me I will try to explain again.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is use full text search.  The documentation is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html).

You cannot really do what you want with regular SQL.  The SQL language just does not have the primitive to support detailed text analysis.

There are two modes for full text search.  You probably want the natural language version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have now read about Full text search. I have added an EDIT2, to my post with a follow up question. I will be glad if you could answer that or point me in the right direction.

Comment: @JohnF . . . If you have your heart set on this "95%" matching, then you probably have to do it manually in the application.  On the other hand, `match against` returns a matching value, and you might be able to just put a threshold on that and do it entirely in the database.

Answer (score 0):

for example if you have a table named **users** you can do something like this:

```
$where = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE '%mo%'")->rowCount();
$all = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users")->rowCount();
$percentage = ($where / $all) * 100;
```